# How to replace a web.config setting with the current date while using webdeploy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webdeploy, web-config-transform

I'm using a web.config transform to replace settings with the settings of the selected solution configuration. However, I would like to add a setting that stores the datetime of the publish process. The reason for this is to be able to show a "Last published on" for my customers.

Using config transforms, is there a way to replace a setting with the current date?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this in Visual Studio 2022 with a .NET 6 web application by using PowerShell scripts to add an `<environmentVariable>` with a Publish Timestamp to my `web.config` before publishing, then removing it after publishing.  That way I don't get my local `web.config` altered in source control every time I publish.

I publish to a local folder, then deploy to a shared Production server with Beyond Compare. Having the deployed `web.config` include the timestamp will automatically restart my production IIS worker process, unlocking my main DLL, which fails to copy unless I touch my `web.config`.

1. Create a Powershell script called `beforePublish.ps1` with this code:

   ```
   $webConfig = "web.config"
   $webConfigXml = (gc $webConfig) -as [Xml]

   $publishTime = $webConfigXml.CreateElement("environmentVariable")
   $publishTime.SetAttribute("name", "PublishTime")
   $publishTime.SetAttribute("value", (Get-Date))
   $webConfigXml.configuration.location.'system.webServer'.aspNetCore.environmentVariables.AppendChild($publishTime)

   $webConfigXml.Save($webConfig)
   ```

   - *This assumes you have an existing `environmentVariable` like this in the `<aspNetCore>` tag:*

   ```xml
           <environmentVariables>
             <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
           </environmentVariables>
   ```
2. Create a PowerShell script called `afterPublish.ps1` with this code:

   ```
   $webConfig = "web.config"
   $webConfigXml = (gc $webConfig) -as [Xml]

   $nodes = $webConfigXml.SelectNodes("//environmentVariable[@name='PublishTime']")
   foreach($node in $nodes) { $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node) }

   $aspNetCore = $webConfigXml.SelectSingleNode("//aspNetCore")
   $aspNetCore.SetAttribute("processPath", $aspNetCore.GetAttribute("processPath").replace("Release", "Debug"))

   $webConfigXml.Save($webConfig)
   ```

   - *As you can see I additionally reverted my `<aspNetCore processPath='bin\Release\net6.0...'>` back to Debug mode to keep my localhost unchanged by the publish to Release mode.*
3. Add this XML to the `\Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml` file inside the `<Project>` tag:

   ```xml
   <Target Name="AddTimestampToWebConfig" BeforeTargets="Publish">
       <Exec Command="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file D:\Documents\wwwroot\PortalApp\Properties\beforePublish.ps1" />
   </Target>
   <Target Name="RemoveTimestampFromWebConfig" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
       <Exec Command="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file D:\Documents\wwwroot\PortalApp\Properties\afterPublish.ps1" />
   </Target>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to use a customer MSBuild task to apply the change.

My wife blogged about adding custom tasks to the build process (as she understands these things better than I).

You might find some useful information on [her blog](http://hastobe.net/blogs/purplekate/archive/2011/07/12/calling-a-custom-msbuild-target-when-building-a-project.aspx) (there are a few related posts).

Alternatively, maybe you could pick up the Last Modified date from a file in your deployment, rather than having it in Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You could post it with that setting blank, then in Application_Start, check to see if it's blank and populate it with the current date if it is.

Comment: Keep in mind that modifying the web.config will cause the app to restart though.