# Insert DateTime.Now to a Web.Config during publish/deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, web-config-transform

I want to have a date when an application was deployed/published in my Web.Config.

Is there a way to achieve that with web.config transformations?

With `xdt:Transform="Replace"` I can replace any node with predefined value, but is there a way to use some custom function to calculate that value (like `DateTime.Now`)?

Comment: check if it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827978/how-to-replace-a-web-config-setting-with-the-current-date-while-using-webdeploy

Comment: thanks, in my particular case it's kind a duplicate.. and the answer about deploying a blank field and filling it on first start seems ok. But maybe there's another solution with config transforms :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with the config transforms (although I'm not 100% certain).

I would suggest using the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) which contains a **DateAndTime** task to get the current Date and a **Detokenise** task to perform token replacement on a file.

You could then either:

1. edit your website csproj file remove the comments around the **AfterBuild** target, and place your tasks there
2. write a separate MSBuild script and run that after your site builds.

Hope that helps.